# How to ask for re-tagging of questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

I am new to tex.SE. I am getting familiar with the available tags and their meaning here.

How do I ask other users to re-tag questions properly?

What do you think about creating a tag named "please_retag"?

To be more specific: I want to ask others to re-tag questions made by me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of "janitors" active on TeX.SX who try and (re-)tag questions in general (not just specific to some users, like new ones) and attempts to do so consistently. This may be specific to *this* site due to its size and the community members, but it has been working well. As such, best-attempt tagging by newcomers are welcomed, and corrected by experienced members very quickly.

To summarize, I don't think there's a need to tag a question as `{please-retag}`, nor even request a more appropriate retag in the original post.

Comment: And as a rule of thumb, try to use existing tags rather than new tags; it's probably better in most cases if you're relatively new to the site to not add a new tag if you're in doubt.

Answer (score 9):

You can edit a question to change the tags if you have enough reputation. This will notify moderators and 10k+ users about the to-be-approved edit and these can then accept your edit. Making a 'please_retag' tag doesn't really make sense therefore.

Comment: Update: To be more specific: I want to ask others for retaging question made by me.